# Moto G5 Plus can't connect via Socket to a local server

Tags: android, sockets, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat, motorola

I have an application where the smartphone must connect via SSLSocket to a local server. I tested my app on 5 different smartphones: Moto G2 (6.0), Redmi 3S (6.0.1), LG K5 (6.0), Moto G5 Plus (7.1.1) and OnePlus 5 (8.0). The Moto G5 Plus was the only one to show this problem.

This is the line that causes the problematic behaviour. All tests where done on the same network.

```
socket = (SSLSocket) sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(serverAddress, serverPort);
```

Is there any known problem with Moto G5 Plus or with Android 7+ around this behaviour?

**EDIT:** Some more tests are leading to an idea of Android system trying to force the Socket to connect through mobile network when identifying that WiFi interface is connected, but with no internet. **Is there any way to enforce the Socket to use WiFi instead of mobile network?**

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I didn't test this so I'm really not sure if it works.

The `Network` class has a `bind(Socket)` method, maybe you could find the wifi network and then bind it to your socket. From the doc it seems that this is what you need, it says:

```
/**
 * Binds the specified {@link Socket} to this {@code Network}. All data traffic on the socket
 * will be sent on this {@code Network}, irrespective of any process-wide network binding set by
 * {@link ConnectivityManager#bindProcessToNetwork}. The socket must not be connected.
 */
```

The `Socket` shouldn't be connected before binding to the network, so I think you should create it with `socketFactory.createSocket()` and connect it only after the binding.

So, you should first find your `Network` (Kotlin):

```
val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
val wifiNetwork = connectivityManager.allNetworks.firstOrNull {
    val info = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(it)
    info.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI
}
```

or (Java)

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
Network wifiNetwork = null;
for(Network network : connectivityManager.getAllNetworks()){
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(network);
    if(networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
        wifiNetwork = network;
        break;
    }
}
```

Then bind it to the `Socket` and finally connect (Kotlin):

```
wifiNetwork?.bindSocket(socket)
val socketAddress = InetSocketAddress(hostname, port)
socket.connect(socketAddress)
```

or (Java)

```
if(wifiNetwork != null){
    wifiNetwork.bindSocket(socket);
}
InetSocketAddress socketAddress = InetSocketAddress(hostName, port);
socket.connect(socketAddress);
```

Note, it needs `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for such a complete answer. I'll try it and return to you!

Comment: @Minoru sure I'm curious to know if it works xD btw, I updated the answer, you need to add `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission if you don't have it already